# Clicking on a selection, then passing value to a "buy now" button which links to unique url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I want to do a selection process where the user has a choice of three items, they pick on of them and this "value" is passed to another button where you then click on "buy now" and it will amend the url, so the choices could be:

- 1st: 45 pounds (with a url of website.com/price45)
- 2nd: 40 pounds (with a url of website.com/price40)
- 3rd: 30 pounds (with a url of website.com/price30)

(button) buy now (/button) (this button will direct them to the above button value)

Comment: You should show some effort of posting your tried code

Comment: does not work, but a free start: http://jsfiddle.net/oeg20tk6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the type of thing you were after - 
http://codepen.io/ashconnolly/pen/OyaBaQ/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('button').click(function() {
        $('button').removeClass('button_selected');
        $(this).addClass('button_selected');

        var val = $('.button_selected').attr('data-value');
        $('p span').html("http://www.website.com/price" + val);
        $('a').attr("href", "http://website.com/price" + val);
    });

});
```

It has some jQuery that gets the data-value attribute from the selected button and applies it to the link.

Comment: Spot on Ash! Exactly what I was looking for, earned yourself a coffee.

Answer (score 0):

What I feel you should do is

1. Create a global variable for eg: x
2. create a function which will accept a value y eg: function passVal(y){x = y}
3. When a user clicks on the choices, call passVal function with the value selected by user
4. on clicking "buy now" append the value of "x" to your url string.

Hope this helps :)